# getting values out of json array - Java

Tags: java, android, json

this is my json array:

```
{"code":1,"auth_key":null,"gps_key":null,"status":"Success","message":"Changes found","data":null,"result":["2015-08-03 01:05 PM: Scheduled visit to Kandy Food City under Food City canceled.","2015-08-03 05:45 PM: Scheduled visit to Kandy Food City under Food City canceled.","2015-08-09 05:25 AM: Scheduled visit to Kandy Food City under Food City canceled.","2015-08-05 09:45 PM: New visit added to Kandy Food City under Food City."],"request_date_time":"2015-08-03 18:32:48"}
```

i am trying to get the **result** out of the json string one by one. it's not working for me .
here is my java code

```
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(value);
            JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jObject.get("result");
            Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
```

Comment: _its not working for me_, so what is happening exactly?

Comment: which json library you are using

Comment: result it self is a key but you are saving array inside it instead of it's value, what you can do is have a array called result and save key:value pair in that

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/ : check this out

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. Use it as a reference :

```
JSONArray moviewJArray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i=0;i<moviewJArray.length();i++)
{
     String movieName = (String) moviewJArray.get(i);
     // Do anything with string
}
```

In your case :

```
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jObject.getJSONArray("result");
for (int i=0;i<msg.length();i++)
{
     String visit = (String) msg.get(i);
     // Do anything with string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(value);
    // Getting JSON Array node
    JSONArray contactList = jObject.getJSONArray("result");
    for(int i=0;i<contactList.length();i++){
        Log.e("contact->",(String)contactList.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

iterator.next will give you JSONObject. then you have to do the below steps to get the result.

```
 String jsonData="{\"code\":1,\"auth_key\":null,\"gps_key\":null,\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Changes found\",\"data\":null,\"result\":[\"2015-08-03 01:05 PM: Scheduled visit to Kandy Food City under Food City canceled.\",\"2015-08-03 05:45 PM: Scheduled visit to Kandy Food City under Food City canceled.\",\"2015-08-09 05:25 AM: Scheduled visit to Kandy Food City under Food City canceled.\",\"2015-08-05 09:45 PM: New visit added to Kandy Food City under Food City.\"],\"request_date_time\":\"2015-08-03 18:32:48\"}";  
              org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser jobj = new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
        JSONObject jobj1 = (JSONObject)jobj.parse(jsonData);
JSONArray jArr = (JSONArray)jobj1.get("result");
java.util.Iterator itr =  (java.util.Iterator)jArr.iterator();

                while(itr.hasNext())
               {
                    Object o=(Object)itr1.next();
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Already google release an open source library called GSON for parsing json to object

please refer 
https://github.com/google/gson